# OpenCV android NDK build error

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm using NDK to use C++ native code in OpenCV through Android studio.
Every thing is alright except when I'm running this project to an android device I have the following error

> Warning:Native C/C++ source code is found, but it seems that NDK option is not configured.  Note that if you have an Android.mk, it is not used for compilation.  The recommended workaround is to remove the default jni source code directory by adding:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
main {
jni.srcDirs = []
     }
                }
          }
```

and also

> to build.gradle, manually compile the code with ndk-build, and then place the resulting shared object in src/main/jniLibs.
>
> C:\Users\MALIK\Desktop\ImageJ\app\src\main\jni\com_example_malik_imagej_DetectionBasedTracker.cpp
>   Error:(2, 10) 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found 1 error generated.

and when I do the workaround and make jni.srcDir empty , I got error that "cannot resolve corresponding  JNI function "
so the native code won't run and the app crashes , what should I do in this case?
this is my gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.malik.haar"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    commandLine "C:/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/ndk-build.cmd",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = [] } }
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
androidTestCompile files('libs/junit-4.12.jar')
compile project(':openCVLibrary320')
}
```

and this is my Android.mk file :

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)


OPENCVROOT:=C:\OpenCV-android-sdk
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED
include $(OPENCVROOT)/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_example_malik_imagej_DetectionBasedTracker.cpp
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)


LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog -ldl
LOCAL_MODULE := detection_based_tracker

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and this is my Header file of native code :

thanks.

Comment: This is based on a pretty old toolset. OpenCV integration into NDK project in Android Studio with CMake or ndkBuild has became much smoother these days.